# how to wrap observables with error handling

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I use the same error handling for multiple rxjs functions:

```
f1() {
  this.error = undefinded; //*
  obs1$.subscribe({
    next: () => some_code,
    error: error => this.error = error //*
  })
}

f2() {
  this.error = undefinded; //*
  obs2$.subscribe({
    next: () => some_other_code,
    error: error => this.error = error //*
  })
}
```

how do I factor out the code marked with //* (both lines!)

--edit--

I know there is a catchError function in rxjs, but the problem is the code before:

```
this.error = undefined;
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is exactly. `this.error = undefined;`is not a problem per se.

Comment: The problem is one of the main and oldes problems in computer programming: I had to write the lines marked with //* twice, but I want to write them only once, encapsulated in a function.

Comment: Is `undefinded` meant to be `undefined`?

Comment: yes !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by implementing a custom operator:

```
errorOperator<T>() {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) => concat(
    of(null).pipe(map(() => this.error = undefined), ignoreElements()),
    obs.pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.error = error;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    )
  );
}
```

or:

```
errorOperator<T>() {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) => concat(
    new Observable(subscriber => {
      this.error = undefined;
      subscriber.complete();
    }),
    obs.pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.error = error;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    )
  );
}
```

or:

```
errorOperator<T>() {
  return (obs: Observable<T>) =>
    of(null).pipe(
      map(() => this.error = undefined),
      concatMap(() => obs),
      catchError(error => {
        this.error = error;
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
}
```

usage:

```
f1() {
  of('dummy').pipe(this.errorOperator()).subscribe(
    () => some_other_code
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generic factory method, which takes the Observable as an argument:

```js
errorHandlerFactory(obs, nextFn) {
  return () => {
    this.error = undefinded;
    obs.subscribe({
      next: nextFn,
      error: error => this.error = error
    })
  };
}
```

Comment: No, that is not correct, ```some_code``` is not ```some_other_code```

Comment: The idea is, that you provide everything that differs as a parameter. So you can just pass in the callback for `next()`. Code is adjusted.

Comment: It is ugly, but it answered my question. To pass the "next-handler" as a callback is not rxjs like, I would rather get an observable that I can subscribe or pipe to.

Comment: I can't magically know what you want to do, if you don't specify it in your question... This is not some free code generation service. Maybe try ChatGPT next time.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: look at my other answer for a solution

The best solution so far is the following factory method:

```
errorHandlerFactory<T>(obs: Observable<T>) {
  return () => {
    this.error = undefined;
    return obs.pipe(catchError(error => this.error = error));
  };
}

f1() {
  const obs1$ = of('dummy');
  this.errorHandlerFactory(obs1$)().subscribe({
    next: () => some_code
  })
}

f2() {
  const obs2$ = of('another dummy');
  this.errorHandlerFactory(obs2$)().subscribe({
    next: () => some_other_code
  })
}
```

Thanks to Bastian for his answer.

Or in variation of what AI suggests:

```
handleError<T>(obs$: Observable<T>) {
  this.error = undefined;
  return obs$.pipe(catchError(error => this.error = error));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's one way using a custom operator that wraps the rxjs `catchError` operator

```js
function errorHandler (observable) {
  return observable.pipe(catchError(err => {
    console.error(err); // Do whatever you need with the error
    throw err; // rethrow
  }))
}
```

Use it like this

```js
obs1$.pipe(errorHandler).subscribe({
  next: () => {},
  error: error => {} // You can still handle the error downstream if you need to
});
```

Comment: and where is the ```this.error = undefined``` left?

Comment: That is contextual and depends on how you define your functions. If you have the right `this` inside the handler you can simply assign a property on it the usual way